# Serving static resources with Tomcat: ResponseFacade.setContentLengthLong(J)V is abstract

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have a SpringBoot web service that is served via Tomcat version 8. Using the SpringBoot API is normal, but requesting static resources leads to the following error:

```
[ERROR] 2022-09-27 11:38:00,537 [http-bio-172.17.0.19-8080-exec-1]  [] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception -org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method org/apache/catalina/connector/ResponseFacade.setContentLengthLong(J)V is abstract
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setContentLengthLong(ResponseFacade.java) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.99]
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setContentLengthLong(ServletResponseWrapper.java:135) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
        at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.writeHeaders(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:130) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.getBody(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:96) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeContent(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:129) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:45) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:227) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:555) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        ...
```

Is there a way to solve this? I already tried to exclude the embedded Tomcat from `pom.xml`, which led to a compilation error and configured the document content root in Tomcat's `server.xml` to the path, which also led to the error above.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by going back to Spring Boot version 2.3.9.RELEASE.